# Empty Classes After importing project on eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

i was working on my android project when my computer shutdown accidentally , so the project explorer don't show any project , so i try to import my project using (Import existing project into workspace ) all files are imported but all of them is empty (0 kb) , and even the original project on my workspace is empty , please can any one help me because i don't have any backup :(. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check if the folder where the actual folder where the source code is exists. If it does, than simply create a new project, drag the contents of the `src` folder into the project and eclipse will ask you to either copy or link the files. Click copy and then copy any other files that you may need. e.g. `res` folder, `sounds` folder.

Comment: the files are empty . i try to open them using an edit text but there no code .

Comment: Well that means that your code is gone! :( You could try right clicking the `src` folder in windows explorer, click properties and previous versions. Try to find one before the time your computer shut off. Try posting a dropbox or google drive link of the project folder so I can try to help you out.

Comment: hello , i try the previous version , but its say there are no previous folder, and her is the google drive link , https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-tSJ16Xo3dmQl9wd0RkWWVTMjQ/edit?usp=sharing thanks

Comment: Ok I requested access. Could you let me in? You should enable previous versions in windows because it helps a lot in situations like these. It happened to me when I was working on the same project on two computers and it corrupted the project.

Comment: Also is there content in the `bin` folder?

Comment: hello you are in , yes there are files on the bin folder but every thing is 0kb

Comment: Hello, I have seen the folder and this is really weird. Try searching some tools to recover permanently/semi deleted files. It may help you out.